# How to show two images in row of ListView?

Tags: java, android

i have one small problem: I need my app to show images in gallery like this :

> image image
>
> image image
>
> image image

I am using `listView` and need to use for loops to show images in that way.

I am using Android studio

Comment: My suggestion is to use `HorizonalScrollView` or `RecyclerView` with `horizontal` layoutmanager.

Comment: Plz post your code

Comment: You can follow this tutorial: https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html , or some other tutorial. If you get stuck on some particular problem, come here again, and post some code.

Answer (score 1):

try this using `RecyclerView` you can achive this

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**and create layout like below**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[RecyclerView demo link](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

Here use this layout for your listView row and populate the imageview according to your data from your listview adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowLayout">

     <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/image1"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/image2"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/image3"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/image4"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/image5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is very very ordinary answer !!